# Passing char of a string to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, char, parameter-passing

In my program I want the function replacef(char m) to replace the letter A/a with the number (initialized as a char). However, when I invoke the function in a for loop and if I write for example "Alabama"(without the quot.marks), the program returns the string unchanged. How can I pass the character so that this function works properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string n;
void replacef(char m)
{
    switch (m)
    {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    m='1';
    }
}
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<n.length(); i++)
    {
        replacef(n[i]);//Replace the current char in the string
    }
    cout<<n<<endl;
}
```

Comment: s/`void replacef(char m)`/`void replacef(char& m)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the parameter with reference. Replace `void replacef(char m)` with `void replacef(char& m)`.

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: @Y.Ivanov Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Your replace function must receive the char by reference.

```
void replacef( char& c){ ...
```

I think you should also have a look at std::replace function that does just what you need.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace

M2c

Answer (score 1):

You should use references or pointers to do this.

**Here is the code to do that:-**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string n;
void replacef(char &m)
{
    switch (m)
    {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    m='n';//you can choose any character to replace in place of 'm'
    }
}
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<n.length(); i++)
    {
        replacef(n[i]);//Replace the current char in the string
    }
    cout<<n<<endl;
}
```

if you still have any query then comment